Auto mounted drive can't be seen in Samba
Bookworm auto mounts my external HDD, but I'm unable to see it with Samba no matter what I try with setting the share path in the smb.conf file.
I can only see what's in my home directory, and
/mnt isn't there. I can see and use the mounted drive in Filezilla, but not Samba.

Could you possibly explain exactly what you mean by "I'm unable to see it with Samba no matter what I try with setting the share path in the smb.conf file" Also, you say that your external HDD is being auto mounted, but have you confirmed that? Please run lsblk --fs from a terminal & edit your question with the results of that command.

automount is a "feature" (aka bug) of the File Manager; drives are mounted ONLY for the user if the GUI is active and don't appear in the same place. If you WANT to mount do it properly in /etc/fstab. findmnt will show mounted drives.

I always mount my drive in a script e.g sudo mount.cifs //Remote.local/Images /mnt/Image -o user=xxx for a remote drive - that way they mount in a known place with known permissions.
For a local drive sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/SDA1 but for reliable mount of a known drive UUID or PARTUUID is preferable to partition.

I'm using Samba with win10, and the only way I can actually connect is to us the \rpi4-2\crusader2752939 setting. Thats the server name and my user name. My samba configuration is:

I'm using Samba with win10, and the only way I can actually connect is to us the \rpi4-2\crusader2752939 setting. Thats the server name and my user name. My samba configuration is: [4tbshared]
path = /media/crusader27529/4tbshared
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
public=no

The samba connection is to my home directory, and I can't navigate any higher in the tree to get to the media foler, where the mounted drive is. And I'm absolutely sure that the drive is mounted.

NAME   FSTYPE FSVER LABEL     UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSU>
sda                                                                           >
|-sda1 vfat   FAT32 bootfs    9BE2-1346                             435.9M    >
-sda2 ext4   1.0   rootfs    12974fe2-889e-4060-b497-1d6ac3fbbb4b  177.1G    > sdb                                                                           > |-sdb1                                                                        > -sdb2 ntfs         4tbshared 02D84141D84133E7                        2.8T    >

DO NOT put detail in Comments; EDIT your Question.
